# Can we ask stupid questions here or give stupid answers?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The suggestion (*meta*) is that we take SO discussions here rather than conduct them on SO.  But one of the things I've looked for in a sister-site is the ability to ask things of the community that aren't programming related.  Or to just be unprofessional and generally dopey when the desire strikes.

Will it fly?  Or is this still not the place for off topic and jerky behavior?

Should there be an offtopic.stackoverflow.com in that case?

Comment: Oh, the irony of this question being closed...

Comment: Oh, the questions I missed out on in 2009...

Comment: @Chris: Hey, whats with you guys dusting off this question?  Don't make me self conscious and have to go around deleting embarassing stuff I posted...

Comment: Don't look at me! @Jeff did it! I swear!

Answer (score 4):

You can ask whatever you want, but that doesn't guarantee you're going to like the way the community rewards you for it.

Answer (score 2):

YES          !

Ask whatever you want.  I wouldn't go so far as to say you can ask totally off topic posts (you'll see that people will delete them) but you are going to have MUCH more leeway here from the community I expect.

I personally welcome your stupid questions. (although maybe not your stupid answers).

Comment: to which?????15

Comment: You mean why don't I welcome your stupid answers?

Comment: YEAH! Why be so exclusionary? Stupid answerers need love too...

Comment: You edited your post when I commented.  Hurf.

Comment: ha! I get it.. Look at all the vote love I'm getting for my answer too.  The negative nellies have already started their migration.

Comment: One of your answers has been flagged twice for spam, and another for moderator intervention. This isn't an anything-goes site.

Comment: @Kyle: Well, remember, this is coming from the same guy who thinks stackoverflow.com should be anything goes as well. Enough for him to actually troll stackoverflow.com and use his personal and business relationships with moderators to keep his trolling alive.

Comment: Small correction: the flag, not the post, was by Michael. Still getting used to these new tools. However, there he still does have a post with 2 spam flags.

Comment: I'd vote you down (if I had votes) for the "negative nellies" comment. Channeling your inner Ned Flanders is creepy.

Comment: I don't know a better word to describe it.  Wikipedia has the same problem: http://www.roughtype.com/archives/2009/06/the_sour_wikipe.php

Answer (score 2):

Despite the site being for meta, there is a topic. We should stay on topic and professional.

This is not a [free for all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339/is-meta-stackoverflow-a-free-for-all).

Comment: I get a warm feeling in my heart whenever I see a Rich B answer.  I'm weird.

Comment: @Won't: Must be the Gravatar.